# Automatically turn on hl-line-mode inside org-mode tables

Tags: org-mode, org-table, hl-line-mode

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27048263) my question is whether there is a (simple) way to automatically turn on `hl-line-mode` whenever the cursor is within an org-mode table in an org-mode file.

I tried to find a hook for entering or leaving an org-mode table but I was not successful.

Comment: I've suggested one approach in my answer below. I also added an answer to the other question about getting odd/even row highlighting for org tables use `stripe-table-mode`, which may be all you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Org mode does provide the `org-at-table-p` function that can be used to determine if the cursor is inside an org table.

You would need to check this every time the cursor moves, which could be done using the `post-command-hook`.

```
(defun highlight-current-table-line ()
  (interactive)
  (if (org-at-table-p)
      (hl-line-mode 1)
    (hl-line-mode -1)))

(defun setup-table-highlighting ()
  (add-hook 'post-command-hook #'highlight-current-table-line nil t))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'setup-table-highlighting)
(add-hook 'orgtbl-mode-hook #'setup-table-highlighting)
```

This adds a hook that runs after every command when you are in an org (or orgtbl) buffer, and toggles `hl-line-mode` accordingly.